# How to log JAVA Webservice to a file

Tags: java, web-services, rest, logging, jersey-2.0

I build a Service with JAX-RS (Jersey 2.0) and tried to implement a logger who writes down events like errors or results from the requests. Works fine! :)
Unfortunately it creates a File every time the service is called but it would be nice that he writes it in one file.

Have a look at my code (it's just the relevant part):

```
package webservice.feedbacks;

import java.io.IOException;
// imports

@Path("webservice")
public class DeleteFeedback {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Feedbacklogger");
@POST
@Path("/deleteFeedback")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String setFeedbacks(String incoming){

    FileHandler fh;
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(incoming);

    try {
        fh = new FileHandler("D:/Eclipse-Projekte/SmartliveService/logs/DeleteFeedback_log.log");
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.info("----- BEGINN DES PROTOKOLLS -----");
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {e.getMessage();}

    int id = jsonObj.getInt("id");

    String result = executeQuery(id);

    logger.info("----- ENDE DES PROTOKOLLS -----");

    return result;
}

private String executeQuery(int id) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {logger.info("Treiberfehler: " + e.getMessage());}

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try{...} catch(SQLException e){
        logger.info("SQL-Fehler: " + e.getMessage());
        return "error";
    } finally {     
        try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close();} catch (Exception e) {logger.info("Das Statement konnte nicht geschlossen werden: " + e.getMessage());};
        try { if (con != null) con.close();} catch (Exception e) {logger.info("Die Verbindung konnte nicht geschlossen werden: " + e.getMessage());};
    }
    return "success";
}
}}
```

As you can see I created a `FileHandler`. I got this from a tutorial because I'm not that familiar with JAVA as I had been a few years ago. The code just made a Database-query and sends the results.

So, how do I have to write my code that it logs to one file instead of creating a new one every time the interface is called?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You're using logging wrong. Configure it with a config file instead of programmatically. Now you're adding a handler to the logger every time the method is called.

Comment: Yeah. Ok. I intentionally tried to get a bit more information. Perhaps you can post the link from the java-docs or other resources where I can have a look at. But thank you for your feedback. :)

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of the logging framework you're using. This question isn't about webservices or files, it's about you not knowing how to use the logging framework properly.

Comment: Most probably you are looking for this info:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html Please look at log method available in super class.

Comment: @Kayaman: Then please try to help me to understand it. You are the expert of us and as I said I got the looging-code from a tutorial! So then give me source where I can read about logging in Java because I don't even know what a logging-framework is. Please stop treating me like I don't know anything just because you are an expert.

Comment: @Tinki: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should not initialize the filehandler everytime method is called. Maybe you should make it static or initialize it in the constructor. See append also.